# How can I add readout error in constructing a quantum noise model?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, error-correction, error-mitigation

I'm trying to construct a quantum noise model with readout error only: [`qiskit.providers.aer.noise.NoiseModel.add_readout_error`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.noise.NoiseModel.add_readout_error.html#qiskit.providers.aer.noise.NoiseModel.add_readout_error). However, when I try to specify the qubits for my error (there will be 3 qubits), it seems like the program doesn't have a very clear constraint on how I can define that. Here's my code:

```
prob_nmc = [[0.571787, 0.117113, 0.117113, 0.023987, 0.117113, 0.023987,
        0.023987, 0.004913],
       [0.103335, 0.585565, 0.021165, 0.119935, 0.021165, 0.119935,
        0.004335, 0.024565],
       [0.103335, 0.021165, 0.585565, 0.119935, 0.021165, 0.004335,
        0.119935, 0.024565],
       [0.018675, 0.105825, 0.105825, 0.599675, 0.003825, 0.021675,
        0.021675, 0.122825],
       [0.103335, 0.021165, 0.021165, 0.004335, 0.585565, 0.119935,
        0.119935, 0.024565],
       [0.018675, 0.105825, 0.003825, 0.021675, 0.105825, 0.599675,
        0.021675, 0.122825],
       [0.018675, 0.003825, 0.105825, 0.021675, 0.105825, 0.021675,
        0.599675, 0.122825],
       [0.003375, 0.019125, 0.019125, 0.108375, 0.019125, 0.108375,
        0.108375, 0.614125]]
readout_noise_model_nmc = NoiseModel(basis_gates = ['cx', 'id', 'reset', 'rz', 'sx', 'x'])
readout_noise_model_nmc.add_readout_error(prob_nmc, [0,1,2])
print(readout_noise_model_nmc)
```

Where `prob_nmc` is my 8 by 8 confusion matrix. The simulation result based on this model and qubit list doesn't quite make sense, so I wonder if there's anything wrong with the way I added the readout error. I found the code still works if I replace `[0,1,2]` with `[0,-2,1]`, the latter is obviously incorrect.

Is there anything wrong with my error model? I thought `[0,1,2]` represents the noise of 'physical qubits' of my simulation model. Am I understanding that correct? Thanks!

Comment: see also: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/26688

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem. We should add the noise separately for each qubit, instead of finding the total matrix and then constructing the noise model:

```
readout_noise_model_nmc.add_readout_error(probabilities, [0])
readout_noise_model_nmc.add_readout_error(probabilities, [1])
```

I'm still not clear why we can't assign all the errors at once.

Comment: Can you add a full snipett on how ti actually implement it? I mean, I cannot understand where this goes exacty. I am trying to implement such a noise model (asymmetric readout) on the QAOA example from Qiskit but I could not understand where exactly this noise goes.

Comment: is `probabilities` here the same as `prob_nmc` from the original question? This seems not to work in the current qiskit release